# Original size bitmap using BitmapFactory decodeByteArray

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

How can I construct original sized bitmap from byte-array?

```
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(b64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length, options);
```

The problem is that created bitmap is couple of times smaller (cca 3 times) than original ...

Comment: This looks pretty much correct to me, assuming the byte[] has the correct format. Since you don't write anything about what's wrong, there's no answer to your question.

Comment: I'm using BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     opt.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
     opt.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
     opt.inScaled = false;
even if the options you use should work. Try it. If it doesn't help then your input data isn't correct (as in original bitmap size).

Comment: Weird (at least to me), but this was the key: options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT; Thank you @EmanuelMoecklin Will you post answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to mark my answer as correct ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
opt.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
opt.inScaled = false;
```

According to the documentation it should work with opt.inScaled=false only but this is Android after all...
I've been using that code for many years now and it works perfectly for me.